# Angular How to add a loader animation while Fetch data from API?

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to show loader While fetching data from API, how should I achieve this, please help.
as of now if the length of product list is 0 then I'm showing loader bt this is not the proper way

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngIf="! CoffeeItemList?.length" class="mt-5 text-center">
     <img src="https://chickenrecipeseasy.top/images/loader.gif"/>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
constructor(private getDataListingService: DataListingService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGlobalSearchList('');
    this.getAllData();
  }
  getAllData() {
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
    });
  }
  getGlobalSearchList(type) {
    this.CoffeeItemList = [];
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
      let data = [];
      data = value.data;
      console.log(data);
    }
    });
  }
  getSmartSearchValues(search) {
    if (search === '' ) {
      this.getAllData();
      return false;
    } else {
      this.getGlobalSearchList(this.type);
      this.searchText = this.type;
      }
    this.getDataListingService.searchList(search).subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: You can create an `Http Interceptor` class and start/stop loader on any Http request/response respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, declare in `component.ts` - `showLoader` default false.

```
getAllData() {
    this.showLoader = true;
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
      this.showLoader = false;
    });
  }
```

```
<div *ngIf="showLoader" class="mt-5 text-center">
       <img src="https://chickenrecipeseasy.top/images/loader.gif"/>
    </div>
```

Last where you show data `*ngIf="!showLoader"` add this condition.

Answer (score 0):

with ng if else and finalize pipe like so:

```js
  getSmartSearchValues(search) {
    if (search === '' ) {
      this.getAllData();
      return false;
    } else {
      this.getGlobalSearchList(this.type);
      this.searchText = this.type;
      }
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.getDataListingService.searchList(search).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
  ).subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
    });

  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading" class="mt-5 text-center">
       <img src="https://chickenrecipeseasy.top/images/loader.gif"/>
    </div>
<ng-template #loading>
 Loading...
</ng-template>
```